# How to monitor device's AC current profile?

Tags: power-supply, current-measurement

I have a specific question at the bottom of this post, but a little background is needed.

I recently got a new medical device (a CPAP machine).  Its power supply looks very similar to a typical laptop supply:

```
AC Input:  100-240V 50/60Hz 1.0-1.5A or 115V 400Hz 1.5A
DC Output: 24V 3.75A
```

When I plug in the adapter to the mains it causes all the LED lights on that house circuit to flicker erratically at about 1 to 2-second intervals.  The flicker is just a slight momentary, barely perceptible dimming.  The flicker is similar to (but more subtle than) that caused by a laser printer "waking up" out of sleep mode, but this power brick shouldn't draw anywhere near enough amps to cause the same effect.

This happens even with nothing plugged into the "load" side of the adapter.  The previous CPAP device caused no such flickering.

Here's a picture of the label (click for larger view):

[image]

Question: Before I call ResMed tech support I want to determine if the power adapter is really causing momentary high current surges.  Is there an off-the-shelf device I might be able to rent or borrow that would produce a moment-by-moment record of the current draw?  It would probably have to have pretty high resolution, at least 60Hz.

Side question: Would someone design a power supply so that it takes short pulses of high current from the mains instead of continuous low current?

Comment: Data recorders or a digital storage scope - cost may be an issue ...

Comment: Sounds like a combination of very week grid we’re you live and crappy design of the product.

Comment: I have been running into the same problem for about the last 3 years after I brought home my Resmed Airsense 10. I see that this was posted a few years ago without any results, so did you fix the problem?